# Como obtener el error que recibo en los XHR responses

Tags: vue.js, apollo, error500

En mi backend tengo una serie de validaciones a la hora de iniciar sesión. Estas validaciones devuelven errores. Estos errores los veo (desde el frontend) en el inspector de chrome, en la pestaña network, filtrando los XHR (imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que, si yo a la acción `login` de mi front-end le pongo un `try catch`, el error que atrapa (y muestro por consola) no tiene todos los detalles. Solo dice `Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500`.

Yo quiero mostrar alertas personalizadas y para ello me vendría bien poder **obtener el error tal cual lo estoy viendo en el inspector del navegador**.

> Login en el backend

```
async loginUser(_, { input }) {
        const { errors, valid } = validateLoginInput(input.username, input.password)
        if (!valid) {
            return new UserInputError("Errores:", { errors })
        }
        let user = await User.findOne({ username: input.username })
        if (!user) {
            user = await User.findOne({ email: input.username })
            if (!user) {
                errors.general = "El usuario o e-mail ingresado no se encuentran registrados"
                return new UserInputError("Error de credenciales", { errors })
            }
        }

        const match = await bcrypt.compare(input.password, user.password)

        if (!match) {
            console.log("tengo errores en valid: ",errors)
            errors.general = "La contraseña es incorrecta."
            return new UserInputError("Error de credenciales", { errors })
        }


        const token = generateToken(user)

        return {
            ...user._doc,
            id: user._id,
            password: 'null',
            token
        }
    },
```

> Login en el front-end

```
async loginUser({ commit }, userData) {
    try {
        let { data: { loginUser } } = await apolloClient.mutate({
            mutation: LOGIN_USER,
            variables: userData
        })

        const user = {
            username: loginUser.username,
            email: loginUser.email,
            id: loginUser._id
        }

        const token = loginUser.token
        commit('loginUser', user)
        commit('setToken', token)
        localStorage.setItem('apollo-token', token)
        router.push('/inicio')
    } catch (err) { 
        console.log(err)
        // ACA QUIERO VER EL ERROR DE LA IMAGEN
    }
},
```

Alguien sabe como hacer eso? Estoy usando Vue 2 con Apollo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `UserInputError`, es probable que ahí estés enviando un encabezado de error 500 y es lo que no permite ver el detalle de los mensajes. Por otra parte, para evitar ataques, es recomendable no dar pistas al usuario, si algo no es correcto, el mensaje debería ser único: _"Usuario o contraseña incorrecto."_ o algo similar.

Comment: @Triby en este momento estoy en la calle, luego lo subo, pero también me sucede lo mismo si creo un nuevo objeto Error de javascript. Pero cuando llegue a casa edito la pregunta y pruebo la solucion que paso cristian en la respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Triby mirá, en este momento estoy mirando mi codigo y justamente probé cambiar los ``UserInputError`` por el ``Error`` tradicional, obteniendo el mismo resultado. De todas maneras al objeto lo traigo de ``'apollo-server'``. El mensaje de error se imprime correctamente tanto el el postman como el graphiql (si pruebo las queries o mutaciones desde ahí), pero en el front me aparece lo que menciono en la pregunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución la encontré acá: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2810

> Lo que necesito lo encuentro en el objeto `e.networkError.result.errors`

La solución fue agregar dentro del catch:

```
} catch (err) { 
          console.log(err.networkError.result.errors)
    }
```

Y ahi obtengo un objeto con todos los datos del error que recibo del backend.

Answer (score 0):

Debes acceder al catch de la peticion directamente

```
 apolloClient.mutate({
            mutation: LOGIN_USER,
            variables: userData
        })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(graphQLErrorMessages(error))
  })
```

Sacado de otra respuesta [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199311/show-apollo-mutation-error-to-user-in-vue-js)

Comment: claro pero el que responde arma la función ``graphQLErrorMessages`` a partir de lo que hay en el objeto ``e`` del catch. En mi caso, el error que tiene el catch no contiene los mismos datos que sí tiene la respuesta de apollo en los XHR (imágen)